# How do Electrons in a Crystal Lattice form Pair bonds?

Tags: electrons

How do electrons around adjacent atoms in a crystal lattice form pair bonds when they are both negative and should repel each other?

Comment: this answer of mine might help https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262280/if-a-water-molecule-is-neutral-how-do-water-molecules-attract-one-another-by-el/262315#262315

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the bonds are not formed between the electrons, but between atoms, which are electrically neutral, because they also contain positively charged nuclei. It is difficult to give a deeper answer, since there exist many types of chemical bonds and the answer is different for each of them. A good start could be reading about covalent bond in the hydrogen molecule, typically discussed in QM textbooks.

**Update**
The bond types differ from one type of crystal to another, depending on the type of atoms and the crystal structure. For example, in diamond, silicon, GaAs, all the bonds are covalent, like in organic chains. Although in GaAs they are polar covalent, since the nearest neighbors are different types of atoms (otherwise GaAs and diamond have the same crystal structure). In graphite, the bonds are covalent within each graphene layer, but the coupling between the layers is via van-der-Waals forces. Metals are usually held together by metallic bonds, where electrons are shared by all the ions - one can think of it as a generalization of a covalent bond to more than two atoms (i.e. N electrons are shared by N ions).

Comment: Thanks. I have a basic understanding of normal chemical bonds including covalent bonds, where the atoms are trying to make up standard numbers of electrons in their outer shells. It was just crystal lattices, like in semiconductors, where I thought the electrons where somehow binding together.

Comment: I added more specific examples to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I get the general idea. It is a structure of covalent bonds. The bit about graphite was particularly interesting, with covalent bonds within layers & van-der-Waals forces between. The quantum stuff is a bit over my head, like the forces that keep the single electron around a hydrogen atom in orbit with no other electrons to repel it & keep it up there. I assume the various shaped electron clouds around atoms are formed by the combination of attraction to the nucleus & repulsion from each other.